# How to create a counter without libraries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, counter

I want to build a ***counter***(using only **"pure" python --> without libraries**) that with a ***list of countries_nametags***, it will *identify it on a **dictionary*** and count the **continent associated** to that **country_nametag**.

Example:

```
continent_dict = {'BR': 'America','GEO': 'Asia','JP': 'Asia','SWZ': 'Africa','GER':'Europe','SRB': 'Europe','ARG': 'America'}
```

List:

```
countries = ['PT','ARG','GEO','JP','SRB','BR']

continent_counter = {'America':0, 'Asia':0,'Africa':0,'Europe':0,'Oceania':0} #dictionary that stores the number of occurencies
for country in countries:
    continent_counter[continent_nations_dict[country]] = 1
Max_Continent = max(continent_counter, continent_counter.get)
```

It gets **error**...(probably in the way i get ***max_continent values?***)

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a dictionary that has the name of the continents as keys, and the number of countries associated with each one as a value.

```
continent_counter = {'America':0, 'Asia':0,'Africa':0,'Europe':0}#,etc...
for country in countries:
    continent_counter[continent_dict[country]] += 1
Max_Continent = max(continent_counter, key=continent_counter.get)
print(Max_Continent)
```

In case two continents are equal (same and highest number of countries associated with them), this will only give you one of them as an output. If you need both of the continents, you can add this to the previous code:

```
All_Continents = [] #Creates the list that will contain all the highest 
                    #ranked continents
for key, value in continent_counter.items(): #loop over continent_counter
    if value == continent_counter[Max_Continent]: #if we find a max val
        All_Continents.append(key)                # we append the name of the 
                                                  #continent to the list
print(All_Continents)
```

Comment: Thanks mate! It's exactly this! I already discover the first part of the code before seeing this but that part2 was top notch!

Answer (score 0):

You can 'map' the array values as list of continents from dictionary and calculate most frequent continent with 'max`

```
  c_list=list(countries.map(lambda x: continent_dict[x])
  max( set(c_list), key=c_list.count)
```